# Multiplication of a constant on raw data while creating a graph in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm intending to create a graph which purpose is to give a visual understanding of how different costs changes depending on production volumes. However the costs are expressed in USD, while the production is expressed in tonnes. This causes the line representing the production to appear to be "flat" across the x-axis. I therefor want to change the production unit to be kilograms instead of tonnes to "normalize" the lines to have similar values, thus enabling a much clearer basis of comparison between the costs and production.

I have my production volumes and costs represented in a worksheet. Is there a way to represent the production volumes in the graph in kilograms instead of tonnes without needing to:

```
 1) Multiply the production volumes by 1000 in the worksheet itself? or
 2) Add additional data multiplied by a 1000 which is hidden?
```

The constraints 1) and 2) is due to having so much data to adjust.

EDIT: What I've tried is to add an additional y-axis for the production making it to be a histogram to make it different from the costs represented by lines, but it doesn't look that great.

Also, I've tried to click on the line in the graph to see:

```
 =SERIES(Indata!$A$15;Indata!$C$2:$DR$2;Indata!$C$15:$DR$15;4)
```

and added "*1000" in the back. It gave me error.

Also, trying to edit the data and add "*1000" with error too.

Comment: @pnuts Not quite sure what you mean. You mean right click the line and select "Select data". I did not find anywhere to paste anything in there

Comment: Excel `Series` formulas are not normal formulas.  You cannot add additional math (or any other formulas) to them.  You are also limited on using named ranges in them.  If you can live with a secondary axis that is one way to get multiple series with different units.  Your other option is to modify the data (like @pnuts recommends) or create a new range doing the math and plotting that (keeping original data intact).